# Execute suspending function in jdbi's "inTransaction" handle

Tags: kotlin, transactions, suspend, jdbi

I'm currently working on a kotlin project and for the database layer I'm using jdbi (instead of an ORM I want to use something where I can write plain SQL).

I have to execute multiple statements in a transaction and the statements are already packed in suspending functions. To run multiple statements in one transaction I try to use the following code:

```
suspend fun <T> withinTransaction(fn: suspend (Handle) -> T): T =
        jdbi.inTransaction<T, Exception> { handle ->
            fn(handle)
        }
```

This is not working, because the `inTransaction` handler of the jdbi library is not defined as a suspending function and because of this the compiler is complaining with the following message: `Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body`.

Is there a way how I can still execute the suspending SQL statements inside a transaction, without using `runBlocking`?